# Get AutoText content from Rich Text Control Field into header?

Tags: microsoft-word, forms, rtf

I am trying to add

- Title
- Date
- Description

to the header of a Word document from the content of a Word document. The Word document contains custom Rich Text content control fields. Is it possible to display the content of a specific text field in the header?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can include specific fields inside headers. The only thing you have to do is update fields for the header and the document *separately*

If you have today's date within the document and you want to include it in the header:

[image]

If this date changes just update the field *within* the header using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>F9</kbd>

[image]

This works with any field; all you have to do is make sure both the document and header fields update each time. Word treats each block separately, but I'm sure it's also possible to automate field updates with a macro as well.